# SQL query, select from table1 order by table2 rows

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am trying to select a list of friends from a table, which works fine. However now I am trying to order the results by another table, which is the users online status/recent online activity.

The query I am trying to use is (The error is: Unknown column 'friendID' in 'where clause'):

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN f.userID=$session 
    THEN f.userID2 ELSE f.userID 
    END AS friendID
FROM friends f, usersStatus u
WHERE 
    (
           f.userID=$session OR f.userID2=$session
    ) 
    AND friendID=u.userID
    AND f.state='1' 
ORDER BY u.periodicDate DESC, u.setStatus ASC
LIMIT 5
```

now the query that just returns the friends of a user is this:

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN f.userID=$session 
    THEN f.userID2 ELSE f.userID 
    END AS friendID
FROM friends f
WHERE 
    (
           f.userID=$session OR f.userID2=$session
    ) 
    AND f.state='1' 
LIMIT 5
```

The `friendID` should match usersStatus.userID, I then want to order them in the way in the example above. I would also like to add that if the `friendID` is not IN usersStatus table, it should automatically order those rows at the end.

`u.periodicDate` is just the most recent date set by the user, so this would indicate the last time the user was active, so I want the most recently active users to be first.
`u.setStatus` is set depending on what my script determines him to be, so it can be `1`, `2`, or `3`. `1` being `Online`, `2` being `Away`, and `3` being `Offline`.

So like I said above, users that don't yet have a row in this table should automatically be given an `offline` status.

**EDIT**

I have got a query to work as I want it to, however It's extremely messy and must be hugely wasteful of its resources, as I have to GROUP BY friendID in order for it to return users only once. (because my friends database keeps every row, so if a person unfriends someone, it just creates a new row if they return friends etc.)

```
SELECT * FROM usersStatus,

(SELECT
    CASE WHEN friends.userID=$session 
    THEN friends.userID2 ELSE friends.userID 
    END AS friendID
FROM friends, usersStatus
WHERE 
(
     friends.userID=$session OR friends.userID2=$session
)

AND friends.state='1'
) t
WHERE t.friendID=usersStatus.userID 
GROUP BY t.friendID 
ORDER BY usersStatus.periodicDate ASC, usersStatus.setStatus ASC 
LIMIT 5
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of writing

```
AND friendID=u.userID
```

use the actual value for the alias:

```
AND CASE WHEN f.userID=$session 
    THEN f.userID2 ELSE f.userID 
    END = u.userID
```

Comment: Thanks, but I tried this and it gives me an error, You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM friends f, usersStatus u WHERE ( f.userID=1 OR f.userID2=1 ' at line 3

Comment: What happens if you remove AND friendID=u.userID from your first query?

Comment: it returns every row and the users are returned multiple times. However, I did get a query to work as I wanted it to, however it is a huge mess and doesn't work quite right unless I GROUP BY friendID. I will post it in my question below the others.